# Registering @Component annotated class programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-bean

I'm new to spring framework, my problem is to register spring component through the spring application context I tried it with many different ways but no luck yet.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.app")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ContextDataConfiguration
{
   ...
}
```

registered it with

```
@PostConstruct
public void initilize()
{
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.initializeBean( new ContextDataConfiguration(), "contextDataConfiguration" );
}
```

but the other beans specified in the ContextDataConfiguration class are not getting initialized with this approach.

And if I specify the ContextDataConfiguration class in the component scan it is working but it is giving me an error like

> not a managed type class

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that programatically? Usually there is no need for that.

Comment: because ContextDataConfiguration is in a jar and the calling one is in a war.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Bean annotation in a factory method to initialize your bean. So, lets say you have a `MyBean` component and wants to initialize it... You can do this inside your @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public MyBean myBean() {
   MyBean myBean = ... // initialize your bean here

   return myBean;
}
```

Comment: What happens? Does Spring complains that the class does not exist?

Comment: When you define the bean using `@Bean`, you don't need component scan. Maybe your Spring Boot main class is not importing this `@Configuration` class. Try to use `@Import` in the main class to import this file.

Comment: Also, if you need that `ContextDataConfiguration` be scanned, try to use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.app"})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166320/discussion-between-maxexplode-and-viniciusjssouza).

Answer (score 0):

How a about

```
@Bean
public ContextDataConfiguration contextDataConfiguration(){
    return new ContextDataConfiguration();
}
```

This registers an instance of `ContextDataConfiguration` as a bean.

Comment: ContextDataConfiguration has a component scan in it, in this way it is not triggering that scan which is giving me a null pointer when i called it.